# Find the global maxima and minima on the disk when second order deratives are zero

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I have to find global extrema for $f(x, y) = x^2 + y^2 - 12x + 16y$ over the domain $D=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}:  x^2 + y^2 \leq 25\}$ By solving first order partial deratives I found that the critical point is $(6,-8) \Rightarrow 6^2 + (-8)^2=100>25.$ and $f_{x^2}=0=f_{y^2}=0.$ We only viewed problems where second order partial deratives were not zero, so I got stuck there. how do I still find extremas under these conditions (preferably without polar coordinates.) I appreciate your ideas.

Comment: Since $f$ has no singular point inside the disc $D,$ its max and min on $D$ will be attained on the boundary circle. Find the max and min of $g(t):=f(5\cos t, 5\sin t).$

Comment: Or you can just apply some analytic geometry knowledge to recognize that $f$ is the square of the distance between $(x,y)$ and $(6,-8)$. And since squaring is a strrictly increasing function on positive reals, it will be maximized and minimized at the same points as the distance itself. So the question becomes which points in the closed disk about the origin of radius $5$ are closest to/farthest from $(6, -8)$, which is fairly easy to spot geometrically, and to calculate.